# Older version of mysql-devel seems to be missing from Yum?

Tags: mysql, yum

I have been using mysql-devel-5.1.69-1.el6_4 from yum, and in the last day the only available option I can now see is mysql-devel-5.1.73-3.el6_5. Is there a way to get the older version from yum? Is this a regular thing to remove older versions? I would prefer to use the older version because I know it will work with my other libraries/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many repository mirrors only mirror the most recent updated packages because that's what most people need and the disk space for older versions can be high.

If you really need a specific version (and I would generally suggest that you do not and should not rely on a version like that whenever possible) you should be able to get the older package from http://vault.centos.org .

Comment: Is it invalid to worry about breaking dependencies for your code by switching versions? Just curious why you think automatically using the most recent version is better than using a fixed version; I might be wrong and I'd like to learn the correct way to think about this.

Comment: Because the changes between `5.1.69` and `5.1.73` for any properly managed library are going to be intentionally safe for upgrade. That's why only the micro number changed. Additionally, for the way RedHat/CentOS do things the assertion from the distribution is that updates are intended to be safe. Additionally, given the pace of security and bug discoveries in software staying on a given version is opening yourself up to maintaining vulnerability to solved issues.

Comment: Should you test this on a staging server? Absolutely. Should you be overly worried about it for something like mysql like this? No.